# Linebreak for buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

Here is my problem :
I have a `labelframe` (I tested in a classic label too) which contains some buttons with a left alignment for the "-side" option.

These buttons are generated by a loop and I would like to add a "wraplength" to the label for that my buttons can jump a line instead of follow each other side by side.

The loop & buttons code :

```
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        status = CheckStatus(line)
        NewButton = Button(labelframe, state = status, text = line, command = lambda x=line:run(str(x)))
        NewButton.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

The frame which contains the loop :

```
labelframe = LabelFrame(Window, width = 400, height = 150)
labelframe.pack()
labelframe.pack_propagate(False) #I Try this to fix the size of the labelframe.
```

Comment: If you want them in a column, just use `side='top'` and they will stack top-to-bottom.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know but I would like that my buttons appears in line**S**.
In other words, when the label reaches a certain width, a new line would be created.

Comment: Oh, so you want them in a row, but when they hit the edge you want them to wrap?

Comment: @BryanOakley Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, finally, I added an incremental variable & a `if` in my loop. When the variable is equal to 5, a new frame (which contains the buttons) is created. Not sure if it's the most optimized method but I didn't found anything else...

```
def LoadButtons():
FrameInfoText.config(justify = CENTER, text = 'Initialization...')
FrameInfoText.update()
LineFrame = Frame(labelframe)
LineFrame.pack()
ButtonsPerLine = 0
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        StreamPerLine += 1
        if ButtonsPerLine > 5:
            LineFrame = Frame(labelframe)
            LineFrame.pack()
            ButtonsPerLine = 1
        status = CheckStatus(line)
        NewButton = Button(LineFrame, state = status, text = line, command = lambda x=line:run(str(x)))
        NewButton.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        FrameInfoText.config(text = 'Loading...\n'+line)
        FrameInfoText.update()
```